# Trap deadlock error in a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, deadlock

I have a simple SQL stored procedure that I use to update a table, sometimes I face a deadlock that prevents the update.
What can I use in the stored procedure to trap this deadlock and then retry the update again?

Comment: I'd suggest handling that in your application sending the update.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try/catch it
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175791%28v=sql.80%29.aspx
`DECLARE @Tries tinyint
SET @Tries = 1
WHILE @Tries <= 3
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT Authors VALUES 
      (@au_id, @au_lname, '', '', '', '', '', 
'11111', 0)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
    SELECT * FROM authors WHERE au_lname LIKE 'Test%'
    COMMIT
    BREAK
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ROLLBACK
    SET @Tries = @Tries + 1
    CONTINUE
  END CATCH;
END`

Answer (score 1):

You should create an error handler in your application to take care of this. Make sure you give it some time before resubmitting the query.